# I want to skip blobs whose height and width have difference of 10 pixels w.r.t adjacent blobs in binary image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have calculated the location and area of all blobs in a binary image using `bwlabel` and `vertcat`. Now I want to skip those values from array whose blob width and height have difference of more than 10 w.r.t adjacent blob.

```
      3.5000  131.5000  247.0000   12.0000
     73.5000   73.5000   25.0000   42.0000
     88.5000   16.5000   27.0000   42.0000
    108.5000   75.5000   24.0000   41.0000
    124.5000   18.5000   26.0000   42.0000
    143.5000   75.5000   25.0000   42.0000
    159.5000   19.5000   26.0000   42.0000
    177.5000   77.5000   24.0000   42.0000
    233.5000   36.5000   17.0000   29.0000
```

Like from this example I want to skip first row and last row. I just want to draw boundary box from row 2 to row 7.

Third column is width and last column is height of blob.

Comment: There is info missing. How do you define "adjacent" in here? difference bigger than 10 in all directions?

Comment: For example. comparison of first and second row.  abs(247-25) > 10 and abs(12-42) > 10.  So Skip the first row. now if we compare 2nd with 3rd and 3rd with 4th and so on all have abs value of < 10. When we reach second last and last row abs(24-17) < 10 BUT abs(42-29) > 10. So I want to skip last row too. I want comparison of 3rd column and last column only.

Comment: Between the 2nd and 3rd, 73.5-16.5 >10. Actually, all the differences in the second columns are bigger than 10 always.

Comment: Yes. I have no concern with 1st and 2nd column. All I need is 3rd and 4th column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
idx=~any(abs(diff(A(:,3:4)))>10,2);
A2=A(idx,:);
```

Lets understand it.

`diff(A(:,3:4))`  Will calculate the differences between rows, just using the 3rd and 4rd column.

```
ans=
  -222    30
     2     0
    -3    -1
     2     1
    -1     0
     1     0
    -2     0
    -7   -13
```

`abs()` is obvious.

`abs(diff(A(:,3:4)))>10` will tell us how many of those are bigger than 10

```
ans =

     1     1
     0     0
     0     0
     0     0
     0     0
     0     0
     0     0
     0     1
```

`any(abs(diff(A(:,3:4)))>10,2)` will tell us  in which rows there is a value bigger than 10

and the `~` will give you in which rows there are values that are not bigger than 10 for sure.

Then, use the result to get the rows of `A` .

Comment: Nice answer, and nice job understanding the question!

Comment: It skip the first row, last row BUT also skip the second last row (Which I don't want).

Comment: I think Using the values of 'abs(diff(A(:,3:4)))>10' we need only those rows whose 3rd and 4th column is zero.

Comment: That code uses only the 3rd and 4rd column.  If you want to set the threshold lower,  change the 10 to something else.  @Nomi